# How can I run Ubuntu off USB

Tags: 11.10, boot, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I want to know if it is possible to install and run Ubuntu completely off a flash drive without using my computers hard drive. I want to be able to plug in a USB and boot Ubuntu off it. I can't get passed the install screen, and I'm using version 11.10. If this can be done, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Here's how:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: that is NOT the same thing as running ubuntu completely off a usb device.  more elaboration is needed.